# I get errors trying to refresh the page of a website deployed on AWS (S3+CloudFront)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, deployment, amazon-cloudfront

I have deployed a [website](https://www.seeding.gg) via AWS using S3 + CloudFront configured with OAC protocol. I created the website using VueJS. The website works fine until I try to refresh the page with F5 key or I try to go back. There, I get the following error :

```
<Error>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access Denied</Message>
  <RequestId>NDB25DEA4A6T40B7</RequestId>
  <HostId>wk4oKnN8aGNYjhI7w2YZk0PO8lX+06RkFVGAMBYP/+7jt14O7NYY9RUvQwuxaMwr9lPw7ziAZzA</HostId>
</Error>
```

Here you can see my S3 bucket policy :

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCloudFrontServicePrincipal",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": <My S3 ARN>,
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "AWS:SourceArn": <My CloudFront ARN>
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I also have a CORS policy setup on my CloudFront that allows https://www.seeding.gg requests :
[image]

You can test the issue directly by using my website. I hope you guys will be able to help me.

**EDIT**

So I made the error 403 redirect to `/index.html` :
[image]

But now when I refresh the page I get the following error in the console :

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but
the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME 
type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

Comment: Is this some sort of SPA that updates the browser history as you are using it?

Comment: @MarkB Yes I used VueJS to create the website so it uses SPA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you refresh the browser, instead of your SPA being able to handle that request  it sends the full URL to CloudFront, which tries to load that URL from S3, which doesn't exist (since it's some history URL that only makes sense inside the Vue code).

The way I've handled this in the past is to configure the server (CloudFront in this instance) to use your main `/index.html` file as your error page, so that the SPA loads on any URL that hits your domain. Then you can add error checking and `404` responses inside your SPA's router.

Comment: So in fact I will still get the error but instead of showing it to people I redirect directly to the website ?

Comment: It's not really a redirect, but yes, that's the gist of it.

Comment: I edited the post with some new informations

Comment: That error is because your Vue app isn't configured correctly to be served from other URLs. You probably need to set a `<base>` tag https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base You would need to debug that issue in your browser's dev console in order to understand better what is happening there.

Comment: In my ```vite.config.js``` file I have the base parameter set to ```base: './'``` so normally it should already be configured.

Comment: So by changing the base to ```base: '/'``` it works now. Thank you for your help